How to create a dropdown menu for one tab in a quarto dashboard
I am working on a quarto dashboard that has multiple tabs across. I am trying to create a dropdown menu in one tab that has a list of analytes that are run through a for loop to generate a visual that should be displayed with that analyte is selected from the menu.
In flexdashboard I achieved this with:
`r use_analyte` {data-navmenu="analytes"}

at the top of the child document where the visual is created.
Is there an equivalent in quarto dashboards?

Could you please share some reproducible code?
